# What happens if a spidertron remote gets destroyed?

Tags: factorio

I was thinking of building an army of spidertrons, with most of them following a 'leader' around so I can control the entire group's movement with one remote. I was thinking of just using the remotes for the follower spiders to set them to follow their leader, then dumping them in a chest so I wouldn't have to deal with these unstackable items clogging up my inventory. I wonder though what might happen if biters can and destroyed the chest? Would the spiders for those remotes still keep following their previous instructions or would they stop in their tracks until another remote was assigned to them and new orders given?

Comment: This would be easy to test and thereby answer your own question: Save your game, machine-gun the chest yourself, and see what happens to the spidertrons.

Comment: Didn't think about save-scumming (I've never actually done that before for some reason). Thank you.

Comment: Doing this, turns out nothing happened. The other spidertrons kept following the leader. So guess I don't need to worry about those remotes being destroyed. It is sorta hard though to change up their equipment when they're all bunched together. Oh well.